# Difference of Two Arrays Using Perl

Tags: perl, arrays

I have two arrays. I need to check and see if the elements of one appear in the other one.

Is there a more efficient way to do it than nested loops? I have a few thousand elements in each and need to run the program frequently.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the actual nested loop code that you've got so far, that will help us help you find a better way (if there is one).

Comment: If I were you, I would start with CPAN. Take a look at `List::Compare` - and especially, the section at the bottom "If You Like List::Compare, You'll Love ..." It sounds like you may want to look for something implemented in C rather than pure Perl. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::Compare

Comment: Do you mean you need to know if one array is a subset of the other? Or if they're exactly equal? Or if they have the same elements, but in a different order? And do you need to know which elements are missing or just that they're not the same?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Another way to do it is to use [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils)

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = qw( a b c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );

# symmetric difference
my @diff = array_diff(@a, @b);

# intersection
my @isect = intersect(@a, @b);

# unique union
my @unique = unique(@a, @b);

# check if arrays contain same members
if ( !array_diff(@a, @b) ) {
        # do something
}

# get items from array @a that are not in array @b
my @minus = array_minus( @a, @b );
```

Comment: internally Array::Utils also uses HASH for comparing array elements 
 https://metacpan.org/source/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm

Comment: Will be good to see how to check that two arrays are equeal or not

Answer (score 29):

[`perlfaq4`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/pod/perlfaq4.pod#How_do_I_compute_the_difference_of_two_arrays?_How_do_I_compute_the_intersection_of_two_arrays?) to the rescue:

> How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?
>
> Use a hash. Here's code to do both and more. It assumes that each element is unique in a given array:
>
> ```
>    @union = @intersection = @difference = ();
>     %count = ();
>     foreach $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }
>     foreach $element (keys %count) {
>             push @union, $element;
>             push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
>     }
> ```

If you properly declare your variables, the code looks more like the following:

```
my %count;
for my $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }

my ( @union, @intersection, @difference );
for my $element (keys %count) {
    push @union, $element;
    push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
}
```

Comment: The code sample might not quite be the answer to your question, but the advice is right on: use a hash.

Comment: Any particular reason why you've linked to the documentation on `CPAN` and not `perldoc`?

Comment: 1) http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ covers all of CPAN, not just the core docs and modules. 2) I personally prefer the look and feel of the CPAN site to perldoc.perl.org. If you like perl.org better, then that's OK too.

Answer (score 12):

You need to provide a lot more context. There are more efficient ways of doing that ranging from:

- Go outside of Perl and use shell (`sort` + `comm`)
- `map` one array into a Perl hash and then loop over the other one checking hash membership. This has linear complexity ("M+N" - basically loop over each array once) as opposed to nested loop which has "M*N" complexity)

  Example:

  ```
  my %second = map {$_=>1} @second;
  my @only_in_first = grep { !$second{$_} } @first; 
  # use a foreach loop with `last` instead of "grep" 
  # if you only want yes/no answer instead of full list
  ```
- Use a Perl module that does the last bullet point for you (List::Compare was mentioned in comments)
- Do it based on timestamps of when elements were added if the volume is very large and you need to re-compare often. A few thousand elements is not really big enough, but I recently had to diff 100k sized lists.

Comment: For checking whether the elements of one array are present in another array or not, can we use two map functions? Does the two map functions use in our code mean that they should be nested maps?

Comment: @DVK No "going outside of Perl and using the shell" is "more efficient" than using Perl itself. Perl is a highly sophisticated, full-strength, but also terse general-purpose programming language.

In general you should avoid shelling out to use standard UN*X / GNU-Linux utilities unless they are definitely not provided as Perl builtin functions, as these are almost always faster *and* more powerful.

Answer (score 8):

You can try `Arrays::Utils`, and it makes it look nice and simple, but it's not doing any powerful magic on the back end. Here's the `array_diffs` code:

```
sub array_diff(\@\@) {
    my %e = map { $_ => undef } @{$_[1]};
    return @{[ ( grep { (exists $e{$_}) ? ( delete $e{$_} ) : ( 1 ) } @{ $_[0] } ), keys %e ] };
}
```

Since `Arrays::Utils` isn't a standard module, you need to ask yourself if it's worth the effort to install and maintain this module. Otherwise, it's pretty close to [DVK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933418/368630)'s answer.

There are certain things you must watch out for, and you have to define what you want to do in that particular case. Let's say:

```
@array1 = qw(1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5);
@array2 = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
```

Are these arrays the same? Or, are they different? They have the same values, but there are duplicates in `@array1` and not `@array2`.

What about this?

```
@array1 = qw( 1 1 2 3 4 5 );
@array2 = qw( 1 1 2 3 4 5 );
```

I would say that these arrays are the same, but `Array::Utils::arrays_diff` begs to differ. This is because `Array::Utils` assumes that there are no duplicate entries.

And, even the Perl FAQ pointed out by [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933416/368630) also says that *It assumes that each element is unique in a given array*. Is this an assumption you can make?

No matter what, hashes are the answer. It's easy and quick to look up a hash. The problem is what do you want to do with unique values.

Here's a solid solution that assumes duplicates don't matter:

```
sub array_diff {
    my @array1 = @{ shift() };
    my @array2 = @{ shift() }; 

    my %array1_hash;
    my %array2_hash;

    # Create a hash entry for each element in @array1
    for my $element ( @array1 ) {
       $array1_hash{$element} = @array1;
    }

    # Same for @array2: This time, use map instead of a loop
    map { $array_2{$_} = 1 } @array2;

    for my $entry ( @array2 ) {
        if ( not $array1_hash{$entry} ) {
            return 1;  #Entry in @array2 but not @array1: Differ
        }
    }
    if ( keys %array_hash1 != keys %array_hash2 ) {
       return 1;   #Arrays differ
    }
    else {
       return 0;   #Arrays contain the same elements
    }
}
```

If duplicates do matter, you'll need a way to count them. Here's using map not just to create a hash keyed by each element in the array, but also count the duplicates in the array:

```
my %array1_hash;
my %array2_hash;
map { $array1_hash{$_} += 1 } @array1;
map { $array2_hash{$_} += 2 } @array2;
```

Now, you can go through each hash and verify that not only do the keys exist, but that their entries match

```
for my $key ( keys %array1_hash ) {
    if ( not exists $array2_hash{$key} 
       or $array1_hash{$key} != $array2_hash{$key} ) {
       return 1;   #Arrays differ
    }
 }
```

You will only exit the for loop if all of the entries in `%array1_hash` match their corresponding entries in `%array2_hash`. Now, you have to show that all of the entries in `%array2_hash` also match their entries in `%array1_hash`, and that `%array2_hash` doesn't have more entries. Fortunately, we can do what we did before:

```
if ( keys %array2_hash != keys %array1_hash ) {
     return 1;  #Arrays have a different number of keys: Don't match
}
else {
     return;    #Arrays have the same keys: They do match
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this for getting diffrence between two arrays

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @list1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my @list2 = (2, 3, 4);

my %diff;

@diff{ @list1 } = undef;
delete @diff{ @list2 };
```

Comment: This only finds the elements in list1 that are not in list2, but not the other way around.

For example: list1 = (1, 2, 3) and list2 = (1, 2, 4, 5). The difference should be (3, 4, 5) but this finds only one difference (3).

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare each element of @x against the element of the same index in @y, right? This will do it.

```
print "Index: $_ => \@x: $x[$_], \@y: $y[$_]\n" 
    for grep { $x[$_] != $y[$_] } 0 .. $#x;
```

...or...

```
foreach( 0 .. $#x ) {
    print "Index: $_ => \@x: $x[$_], \@y: $y[$_]\n" if $x[$_] != $y[$_];
}
```

Which you choose kind of depends on whether you're more interested in keeping a list of indices to the dissimilar elements, or simply interested in processing the mismatches one by one. The grep version is handy for getting the list of mismatches. ([original post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=951150))

Answer (score 1):

n + n log n algorithm, if sure that elements are unique in each array (as hash keys)

```
my %count = (); 
foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) { 
    $count{$element}++;
}
my @difference = grep { $count{$_} == 1 } keys %count;
my @intersect  = grep { $count{$_} == 2 } keys %count;
my @union      = keys %count;
```

So if I'm not sure of unity and want to check presence of the elements of array1 inside array2,

```
my %count = (); 
foreach (@array1) {
    $count{$_} = 1 ;
};
foreach (@array2) {
    $count{$_} = 2 if $count{$_};
};
# N log N
if (grep { $_ == 1 } values %count) {
    return 'Some element of array1 does not appears in array2'
} else {
    return 'All elements of array1 are in array2'.
} 
# N + N log N
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @a = (1,2,3); 
my @b=(2,3,1); 
print "Equal" if grep { $_ ~~ @b } @a == @b;
```

Comment: To me this looks like it is printing "Equal" if "`1`" is in `@b` ... ?  Maybe `say "Equal" if grep {  $_ ~~ @b } @a && @a == @b ; ` ... but it still seems a little dodgy.

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but easy to understand:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict;
my $file1 = shift or die("need file1");
my $file2 = shift or die("need file2");;
my @file1lines = split/\n/,`cat $file1`;
my @file2lines = split/\n/,`cat $file2`;
my %lines;
foreach my $file1line(@file1lines){
    $lines{$file1line}+=1;
}
foreach my $file2line(@file2lines){
    $lines{$file2line}+=2;
}
while(my($key,$value)=each%lines){
    if($value == 1){
        print "$key is in only $file1\n";
    }elsif($value == 2){
        print "$key is in only $file2\n";
    }elsif($value == 3){
        print "$key is in both $file1 and $file2\n";
    }
}
exit;
__END__
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare). IT has solutions for all the operations that can be performed on arrays.