# How to find values in @array2 but not in @array1

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing Two Arrays Using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl)

How can I print values which exist in `@array2` but not `@array1`? For example, given:

```
@array1 = qw(1234567 7665456 998889 000909);
@array2 = qw(1234567 5581445 998889 000909);
```

the output should be:

```
5581445 doesn't exist in array1
```

Comment: FYI, this is called the "relative complement" (if you only want one way) or "symmetric difference" (if you want both ways) in set theory. This question appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2933347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is via [`Array::Utils`](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw(array_minus);

my @array1= qw(1234567 7665456 998889 000909);
my @array2= qw(1234567 5581445 998889 000909);


my @not_in_a1=array_minus(@array2,@array1);

if(@not_in_a1)
{
    foreach(@not_in_a1)
    {
        print "$_ is in \@array2 but not in \@array1.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    print "Each element of \@array2 is also in \@array1.\n";
}
```

The output is exactly what one would expect:

```
5581445 is in @array2 but not in @array1.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
my %tmp ;

# Store all entries of array2 as hashkeys (values are undef) using a hashslice
@tmp{@array2} = undef ; 

# delete all entries of array1 from hash using another hashslice
delete @tmp{@array1} ;
printf "In Array2 but not in Array1 : %s\n" , join( ',' , keys %tmp ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to compile your own table of array entries, with [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) (since 5.10):

```
print "$_  doesn't exist in array1\n" foreach grep { not $_ ~~ @array1 } @array2;
```