# Perl - determine if an array is a subset of another array

Tags: perl

I have the following code.  Can `isSubset` be written simpler without add-on CPAN modules?

```
my @possibleNames = ("adam", "chelsea");
my @actualNames = ("adam", "chucky", "chelsea");

sub isSubset {
    my ($littleSet, $bigSet) = @_;
    foreach (@{$littleSet}) {
        return 0 unless ($_ ~~ @{$bigSet});
    }
    return 1;
}

printf("%s\n", (isSubset(\@possibleNames, \@actualNames) ? "yes" : "no"));
```

Comment: Just [`use Array::Utils`](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm). There's no reason why you can't use modules from the CPAN.

Comment: `my ($sub, super) = @_; $_ ~~ $super or return 0 for @$sub; 1`, but that is just cosmetics. If the sets are big, or if you test against one set repeatedly, it might be better to use hashes: `$_ ~~ $super` becomes `exists $super->{$_}`. Works only strings, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl

Comment: And if you don't want to pull the module down, go grab the source and use it giving credit where due.

Comment: the smartmatch perl operator is now experimental in perl 5.18, so you'll get a warning in this enviroment.

Answer (score 4):

One fairly efficient way to do it would be:

```
sub isSubset {
    my ($littleSet, $bigSet) = @_;
    my %hash;
    undef @hash{@$littleSet};  # add a hash key for each element of @$littleSet
    delete @hash{@$bigSet};    # remove all keys for elements of @$bigSet
    return !%hash;             # return false if any keys are left in the hash
}
```

Comment: Excellent tiny solution! Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the use of undef.

Comment: @RicardoGemignani: `undef @hash{@keys}` sets the value for every key in the hash slice `@hash{@keys}` to `undef`. (Yes, `undef` can take a list of arguments! See `perldoc -f undef` for more details.) Which is a fast and memory-efficient way to add all those keys to the hash, given that we don't really care what values they have; a lot more efficient than, say, `$hash{$_} = 1 for @keys`.

Comment: Using undef on a slice isn't documented as working (though it does).  Better to do `@hash{@$littleSet} = ();`

Comment: @ysth: Curiously, you seem to be right. I could've sworn it was at least implicitly mentioned in the official perldocs, but I can't find it now. While [`delete`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) is explicitly documented to work on slices, [`undef`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) isn't. I feel like that's probably a bug in the documentation, since it's a common idiom that has worked since the early days of Perl 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @possibleNames = ("adam", "chelsea");
my @actualNames = ("adam", "chucky", "chelsea");

my $is_subset = 0==grep !defined, map { @$_{@actualNames}=(1)x@actualNames; delete @$_{@possibleNames} } {};
```

But seriously, use Array::Utils::array_minus.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to this solution? It looks cool, but it is kinda hard to understand what is going on there.