# Get Similar Values from 2 Arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two arrays ,so i want to get the similar values from both the arrays in a array.

This is array :

```
my @a = qw( a e c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );
```

Please help me how could i get the similar values in Perl.I am new in Perl

Comment: so you want an array with `c,d,e` in it?

Comment: Related: [Comparing two arrays using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a1 = qw( a e c d );
my @b1 = qw( c d e f );

my %seen;
my @final;

@seen{@a1} = (); # hash slice

foreach my $new ( @b1 ) {
    push (@final, $new ) if exists $seen{$new};
}

print Dumper(\@final);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'c',
          'd',
          'e'
        ];
```

Comment: will u please explain this what we are doing in @seen{@a1}=();and then the foreach

Answer (score 2):

try this easy code:

```
my @a = qw( a e c d );

my @b = qw( c d e f );

foreach $my(@a){

        print "$my\n";
        if ((grep(/$my/,@b))){
                push @new,$my;
        }

}
print "new----@new";
```

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to map a hash for seen elements and search the other array using grep.

```
my @a = qw( a e c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );

my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } @a;
my @intersection = grep { $seen{$_} } @b;

print @intersection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the end result contains elements which are present in both the arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @a = qw( a e c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );
my @c;

foreach my $x (@a)
{
    foreach my $y (@b)
    {
        push @c, $x if ($x eq $y);
    }
}

foreach (@c) {print $_."\n"};
```

Output:

```
e
c
d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://vti.github.io/underscore-perl a clone of underscore-js. You can do an intersection of 2 arrays -> http://vti.github.io/underscore-perl/#intersection

```
use Underscore;
_->intersection([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
# [1, 2]
```