# Perl: Print keys from 2 hashes if array of values intersect

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics

I have 2 files which look like the following:

**File1**: All columns except the last are tab delimited

```
space   start   end width   names   score.data  
1   1   1873    24409   22537   DDX11L1 NA
2   1   4361    39370   35010   WASH7P  NA
23  1   690244  724068  33825   LOC100288069    NA
24  1   742750  765214  22465   FAM87B  "rs1;rs2;rs3,"
25  1   751585  772902  21318   LINC00115   "rs3;rs4"
26  1   752970  804826  51857   LINC01128   "rs5;rs6;rs7;rs8;rs9"
27  1   793450  822182  28733   FAM41C  "rs9;rs10;rs11"
28  1   842197  865072  22876   LOC100130417    "rs12;rs13;rs14;rs15;rs16"
29  1   851120  889961  38842   SAMD11  "rs14;rs15;rs16;rs17"
30  1   869582  904679  35098   NOC2L   "rs13;rs17;rs20;rs25;rs27"  
31  1   885966  911099  25134   KLHL17  "rs23;rs25;rs34;rs49"
78  1   1582938 1634243 51306   SLC35E2B    rs45
```

**File2**: All columns except last are tab delimited

```
space   start   end width   names   score.data  
1   1   1096679 1097517 839     DMR1 rs2;rs3  
2   1   1229025 1229590 566     DMR2 rs4  
3   1   1267955 1269432 1478    DMR3 rs7;rs8;rs9  
4   1   1279248 1279795 548     DMR4 rs9;rs10  
5   1   1372628 1374653 2026    DMR5 rs11;rs12;rs14;rs18  
6   1   1842116 1842456 341     DMR6 NA  
7   1   1896556 1897211 656     DMR7 rs13;rs17;rs20
```

**Desired Output**: All columns tab delimited

```
DMR1 FAM87B LINC00115   
DMR2 LINC00115    
DMR3 LINC01128 FAM41C    
DMR4 LINC01128 FAM41C
DMR5 FAM41C LOC100130417 SAMD11
DMR7 SAMD11 NOC2L
```

So basically, I need to check if any `score.data`entries(rs2,rs3...) from `file2`are intersecting with `score.data`entries of `file1`. If they do, I should obtain the key(`names column`) from `file2` and the corresponding keys(`names column`) from `file1`.

eg `DMR1` in `file2` has score.data `rs2;rs3` which intersects with score.data `rs1;rs2;rs3` of `FAM87B` and also `rs3;rs4` of `LINC00115` in `file 1`

Most of the code I've written so far has dealt with cleaning up the first file of "" and NA entries and creating hashes:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $file1 = '/path/to/file1';
my $file2 = '/path/to/file2';

#Open files
open my $fh1 , '<', $file1 or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die $!;


#Read file1
my %gene_hash;
while(<$fh1>){
    chomp;
    my @arr = split; 
    next if $arr[0] eq "space";
    next if $arr[6] eq 'NA';

    my $key = $arr[5]; #Hash key

    my @snps = split /;/, $arr[6]; #to be used as value in hash
    my $first_snp = shift @snps; #remove 1st element from start

    my @first_snp = split /"/, $first_snp; #remove " from start
    unshift @snps, $first_snp[1]; #add 1st element back to beginning


    my $last_snp = pop @snps; #remove last element
    my @last_snp = split /"/, $last_snp; #remove " from end

    push @snps, $last_snp[0];# add last element back to the end
    push @snps, $arr[6] if $arr[6] =~/^rs.*/; #add element even if there are no "" eg SLC35E2B

    push @{ $gene_hash{$key} }, @snps; #assign values to hash
}



my %dmr_hash;
while(<$fh2>){
   chomp;
   my @arr = split;

   next if $arr[0] eq "space";
   next if $arr[6] eq 'NA';

   my $key = $arr[5]; #Hash key

   my @snps = split /;/, $arr[6];#to be used as value in hash
   push @{ $dmr_hash{$key} }, @snps; #assign values to hash

}
```

I tried searching other hash comparison questions here on stackoverflow and all of them had same keys in both the hashes. I also found the [Array::Utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl) tool to intersect two arrays but I'm really not sure how to implement it in my problem.

Thank you for taking the time to go through my question and I will be grateful for ideas and solutions.

Comment: How large are those files?

Comment: The gap between the `names` and the `score.data` columns is a tab in File1 and a space in File2. Is that correct for the real data?

Comment: @simbabque File 1 is about 30,000 lines long and File 2 about 1000 line long

Comment: @Borodin Hei! The gap is a tab for both files...I guess it is not displaying here properly

Comment: @Neal: Okay you can change `split` to `split /\t/` in my code if you wish, but you will also have to `chomp` each record and it makes a difference only if there may be spaces in the data fields themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do as you ask. It build a hash `%mapping` that relates each score entry to all the names that they correspond to in File1, and then interrogates that hash while reading through File2 to build a list of names joined by score entry

The program expects the paths to the two input files as parameters on the comamnd line, like

Note that I have just split each record on whitespace, as the separators in your example data aren't consistent

The output for `DRM7` includes `LOC100130417` which is missing from your desired output. This is correct as `DRM7` from File2 has score entry `rs13` which also appears in the line for `LOC100130417` in File1

```
perl find_joined.pl path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my %mapping;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];
    <$fh>; # Drop the header line

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my @fields = split;
        my $name = $fields[-2];
        my @entries = $fields[-1] =~ /[^";]+/g;
        push @{ $mapping{$_} }, $name for @entries;
    }

    delete $mapping{NA};
}

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1];
<$fh>; # Drop the header line

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $name = $fields[-2];
    my @entries = $fields[-1] =~ /[^";]+/g;

    my %matching;
    @matching{@$_} = () for grep defined, @mapping{@entries};

    if ( keys %matching ) {
        print join(' ', $name, sort keys %matching), "\n"
    }
}
```

#### output

```
DMR1 FAM87B LINC00115
DMR2 LINC00115
DMR3 FAM41C LINC01128
DMR4 FAM41C LINC01128
DMR5 FAM41C LOC100130417 SAMD11
DMR7 LOC100130417 NOC2L SAMD11
```

Comment: Wow! Elegant! I have a few quick questions so that I can better understand the code. **1** What does `delete $mapping{NA}` accomplish? **2** Could you please explain what kind of data structure is `@matching{@$_}`and `@mapping{@entries}`  **3** How `@matching{@$_} = () for grep defined, @mapping{@entries};` works ? This is a novel way to use grep for me.

Comment: And yes thank you for pointing outt hat `DMR7`should have `LOC100130417 `. My bad.

Comment: ***1.*** My code creates an entry for `NA` in `%mapping` because of the way it treats the `score.data` column. Rather than add code to avoid it I've just let it happen and deleted it when the hash is complete. ***2.*** `@mapping{@entries}` is a [***hash slice***](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) -- essentially a way of accessing multiple hash elements in a single expression. ***3.*** In this case, `grep` is filtering out elements of `@entries` for which no element of `%mapping` exists. Accessing a non-existent hash element gives the value `undef` so `grep defined, ...` skips those