# Perl - Filter function for arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, filter

i am trying to create a subroutine that does the following :

1. Takes two arrays as input (Filter, Base)
2. Outputs only the values of the second array that do not exist in the first

Example :

```
@a = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
@b = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

Expected output :   @c = ( 6, 7 );
Called as : filter_list(@filter, @base)

###############################################

sub filter_list {
    my @names = shift;
    my @arrayout;
    foreach my $element (@_)
    {
       if (!($element ~~ @names )){
       push @arrayout, $element;
    }
    }
   return @arrayout
}
```

Test Run :

```
@filter = ( 'Tom', 'John' ); 
@array = ( 'Tom', 'John', 'Mary' );
@array3 = filter_list(@filter,@array);
print @array3;
print "\n";
```

Result :

```
JohnJohnMary
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of Two Arrays Using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/difference-of-two-arrays-using-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass arrays to subs, only scalars. So when you do

```
my @filtered = filter_list(@filter, @base);
```

you are really doing

```
my @filtered = filter_list($filter[0], $filter[1], ..., $base[0], $base[1], ...);
```

As such, when you do

```
my @names = shift;
```

you are really doing

```
my @names = $filter[0];
```

which is obviously wrong.

The simplest solution is to pass references to the arrays.

```
my @filtered = filter_list(\@filter, \@base);
```

A hash permits an efficient implementation (O(N+M)).

```
sub filter_list {
   my ($filter, $base) = @_;
   my %filter = map { $_ => 1 } @$filter;
   return grep { !$filter{$_} } @$base;
}
```

Alternatively,

```
my @filtered = filter_list(\@filter, @base);
```

could be implemented as

```
sub filter_list {
   my $filter = shift;
   my %filter = map { $_ => 1 } @$filter;
   return grep { !$filter{$_} } @_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the difference of two sets. This, along with union, intersection, and a bunch of others are [set operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation). Rather than writing your own, there's plenty of [modules for dealing with sets](https://metacpan.org/search?q=set).

[Set::Object](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Object) is very fast and featureful. I'd avoid using the operator interface (ie. $set1 - $set2) as it makes the code confusing. Instead use explicit method calls.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Set::Object qw(set);

my $set1 = set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my $set2 = set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
say join ", ", $set2->difference($set1)->members;
```

Note that sets are unordered and cannot contain duplicates. This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This uses [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.53/lib/List/Compare.pm), a module with a large collection of routines for comparing lists.

Here you want `get_complement`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Compare;

my @arr1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
my @arr2 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@arr1, \@arr2);

my @only_in_second = $lc->get_complement;

print "@only_in_second\n";
```

The module has many options.

If you don't need the result sorted, pass `-u` to the constructor for faster operation.

There is also the "*Accelerated Mode*", obtained by passing `-a`. For the purpose of efficient repeated comparisons between the same arrays many things are precomputed at construction. With this flag that is suppressed, which speeds up single comparisons.  See [List::Compare Modes](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.53/lib/List/Compare.pm#List::Compare_Modes).

These two options can be combined,  `List::Compare->new('-u', '-a', \@a1, \@a2)`.

Operations on three or more lists are supported.

There is also the functional interface, as a separate [List::Compare::Functional](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.53/lib/List/Compare/Functional.pm) module.