# Perl How to traverse and compare all the elements inside two different array in a faster way?

Tags: perl

Assume there are two arrays, each of them holding very large number of elements. Now I want to compare every each element inside both, if I just do like usual way: using two nested for loop to do the job, it would be quite time consuming. Are there any faster workaround to achieve same purposes? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result? A (N x M) matrix with all the comparison results like `<`, `>`, `==`?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/difference-of-two-arrays-using-perl)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. May be I make the situation more clearer: There are two arrays array1 and array2, both of them are holding a large number of values inside. Two arrays has intersection elements and all the elements can be unique or duplicated. Now that I want to calculate the number of occurances of those intersection elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to speed up lookups, say, by using a hash.

Depending on the specifics, some variation of the following could be used:

```
my %array1;
++$array1{$_} for @array1;
for (@array1) {
   say "$_ isn't in \@array1"
      if !$array1{$_};
}
```

If duplicates are possible:

```
my %array1;
++$array1{$_} for @array1;
my %array2;
for (@array1) {
   say "$_ isn't in \@array1"
      if ++$array2{$_} > ($array1{$_} // 0);
}
```

Comment: It highly depends on what the OP meant with _“compare”_. If she's thinking of set operations like _intersection_ or _difference_, then a hash would help. If she's thinking of `<=>` comparisons, then not.

Comment: @PerlDuck, Not at all. Anything you can do with two nested loops, including the situation where you have duplicates, can be optimized as described. You might been to iterate over a hash instead of an array, that's all.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. May be I make the situation more clearer: There are two arrays array1 and array2, both of them are holding a large number of values inside. Two arrays has intersection elements and all the elements can be unique or duplicated. Now that I want to calculate the number of occurances of those intersection elements.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.