# items in array A that are not in array B

Tags: arrays, perl

What is a quick way to determine items in array A that are not in array B?

So far I have the following, but can it be done in one line?

```
for $aname (@anames)
{
   if (not grep { $_ eq $aname } @hrefs)
   {
        push @anamesremove, $aname;
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933347/2864740 - I searched for ["\[perl\] array find difference"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+array+find+difference) and followed a 'Duplicate Question' link..

Comment: it's not actually an array difference that I'm after

Comment: [Set::Array](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Array) has a difference method that looks promising. You can also do something with hashes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

If you know which array contains the other

```
my @small  = 10..12;
my @large  = 10..15;

my %ref = map { $_ => 1 } @small;

my @diff = grep { not exists $ref{$_} } @large;
```

Not quite one line but efficient.

If it's not known which contains the other then one has to do it both ways.

And then there are various modules for array/list manipulation that can help.

For one, `get_complement` from [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) does precisely what is needed.

---

What you have can be done in one statement, using [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

```
use List::Util qw(none);

my @diff = grep { my $e = $_; none { $e eq $_ } @small } @large;
```

but this has *O(NM-M<sup>2</sup>/2)* complexity, where *N* (large) and *M* (small) are array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner, but this is likely to be faster than yours on big arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

sub difference {
    my ($first, $second) = @_;
    my %except;
    @except{ @$second } = 1;
    return [ grep { not exists $except{$_} } @$first ];
}

my @anames = ("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
my @hrefs = ("two", "four", "six");

my $d = difference \@anames, \@hrefs;
say "@$d";
```

Comment: `@except{ @$second } = 1;` is misleading. How about using `@except{ @$second } = ();` instead.

Comment: @ikegami do you think it's misleading because it might be misconstrued as a count instead of a truthy value?

Comment: It makes it look like the values are being set to  `1` when they're not.

Comment: Nah. I think my way looks better in cases where you just want to create a bunch of keys at once in a hash without caring what the values are (all but one of which will be `undef` of course). Using an empty list looks funny to me. Opinions obviously vary.

Comment: Shawn if you answer someone directly in a comment, use the @ notifier i.e @ikegami else the user will not be informed that you left him/her a comment.

Comment: If you don't care what the values are, you sure go to a lot of trouble to pretend they are `1`. Assigning an empty list is what you are actually doing (except for the "first"), and you should make your code look like it does what it's doing. At the *very least*, use a false value instead of a true one.