# Perl print diff of two files

Tags: file, perl, diff

I am trying to diff between two files and output the diff. My code below works for item exist in file1 but missing in file2, but not working for item in file2 missing in file1. Tried exchange file1 and file2 but not working. Thanks in advance.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $file1 = '1.txt';
my $file2 = '2.txt';



open my $fh, '<', $file2 or die $!;
my $file = [<$fh>];
open $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!;
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp($line);
#print "$line\n";

    my $status = 0;
    for (@{$file}) {
        chomp;
        if (/$line/) {
            $status = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    print $line, $/ if $status == 0 
}
```

File1:

```
15122
16070
61
15106
16704
15105
7303
15201
21
16712
7308
16029
16008
16023
16025
16044
16045
16042
16043
16040
16041
16226
15112
16914
16915
31
16910
16911
16912
16913
16114
7505
1103
16018
16916
```

File2:

```
1103 
15105 
15106 
15112 
15201 
15211 
16024 
16029 
16044 
16051 
16070 
16201 
16225 
16350 
21 
31 
61 
7303 
7505
```

Comment: This "My code below works for item exist in file1 but missing in file2, but not working for item in file2 missing in file1. Tried exchange file1 and file2 but not working." confusingly seems to be a contradiction. Maybe you can give examples of both cases. What is the input of the two pairs of files, what  is the output you get and what would be the output you expect?

Comment: You want lines that are unique to one or the other of the files, and skip lines in common? So something like this bash one-liner? `comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 2):

You had a couple of problems on your code.

After inspecting the files, I see that file2 has some trailing spaces. Since file1 does not have them, you can never match `'1103 '` on the first file, which has no spaces.

`chomp` only removes the last new line (if present) So that won't help with the trailing spaces.

Instead of chomp I would use a regular expression to remove any 'spacy' character at the end of the line. You may use `s/\s*$//` for this purpose.

Also, you are comparing the lines using a regex. That could be problematic unless using some [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Because if you don't, you'll compare `1` on the first file, that will match against `123` on the second file, which is incorrect.

I would use `eq` to compare both lines instead.

So, this is the script with the changes:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $file1 = '2.txt';  # Exchanged files to test the non-working case
my $file2 = '1.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file2 or die $!;
my $file = [<$fh>];
open $fh, '<', $file1 or die $!;
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;    # changed to remove all space-like trailing characters

    my $status = 0;
    for (@{$file}) {
        s/\s+$//;    # changed to remove all space-like trailing characters
        if ($_ eq $line) {    # changed to use a regular comparison
            $status = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    print $line, $/ if $status == 0 
}
```

**Extra tip:**

You don't actualy need to work on file1 with an array reference. You may simply use an array. That way you'll avoid the dereferencing on the `for` loop:

So you could change these lines:

```
...
my @file_content = <$fh>;
...
for (@file_content) {
...
```

**Yet another tip:**

The code may be too slow for large files, since the [cost](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eadamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html) of the algorithm is `O(n^2)`

Probably you may want to use one of the technics described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/difference-of-two-arrays-using-perl).

Comment: 1) This does not answer OP's question: you're not printing lines in `1.txt` that does not appear in `2.txt`; only the other way around. 2) Performance-wise, this is pretty awful: you're iterating through all lines of `1.txt` for each line of `2.txt`. Using a hash to store the lines of `1.txt` would be much more efficient (or `Array::Utils::array_diff` as suggested in ssr1012's answer).

Comment: @Dada I think **I** correctly understood OP requirements... He said his script worked comparing file1 vs file2, but not comparing file2 vs file1. I showed him why his solution didn't work exchaging the files. I also tried to preserve as much as the original script and fix the minimum required to make it easy to understand where the problem was. About the performance: I could refactor the code, but then It would be more difficult to understand where the problem was... By the way, ssr1012 for me doesn't answer the question... It just says: "ey you are doing it wrong. Do it this way instead"

Comment: Mmmh, you might be right, the question is not very clear IMO.

Comment: Regarding using a hash to improve performances: it would actually make the code _less_ complicated since it would remove a loop. `my %file2_lines = map { s/\s+\z//gr => 1 } <$fh>; open $fh, '<', $file2 or die $!; while (<$fh>) { print if ! $file2_lines{$_} }`

Comment: @Dada, 'less complicated' may vary with every person :-). For a beginner with the language, a "for" loop may look like more "natural". Someone learning the language may think "what is that `map` thing? Why that fat arrow inside the "map" curlys?" Yes, there are multiple ways of impriving OP's code, but I think that was not the main reason of the question, but to detect what was wrong.

Comment: In my opinion, using an array and a for loop instead of a hash instead not a choice but a mistake. No matter if the person doing it is a beginner or not, it should not be done.

Comment: What if that is not a "real app", but instead some "loop practising" exercise? What if you know for sure that the files to compare will have some limited lines? If OP finds some performance problem (if ever) he will came here again with a new question. We can give some hints about performance on this question, but not in a way that refactors all OP code without pointing out where the original problem was.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on my understanding its not a line by line matching instead numeric comparisons file by file.

`1) Open the files`

`2) store the contents in the multiple arrays`

`3) Simply compare the two arrays.`

```
   use Array::Utils qw(:all);

   my @file_arr1 = qw(15122 16070 61 15106 16704 15105 7303 15201 21 16712 7308 16029 16008 16023 16025 16044 16045 16042 16043 16040 16041 16226 15112 16914 16915 31 16910 16911 16912 16913 16114 7505 1103 16018 16916);

   my @file_arr2 = qw(1103 15105 15106 15112 15201 15211 16024 16029 16044 16051 16070 16201 16225 16350 21 31 61 7303 7505);

   my @unmatched_arr = array_diff(@file_arr1, @file_arr2);

   my @matched_arr = unique(@file_arr1, @file_arr2);

   print join "\n", @unmatched_arr;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to solve above requirement using List::Compare module https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare

> Script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Grep qw( fmap );
use String::Util qw(trim);
use List::Compare;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file_1 = "file1.txt";
my $file_2 = "file2.txt";

#fmap BLOCK LIST : Performs a map operation on the files in LIST, 
#using BLOCK as the mapping function. The results from BLOCK will be 
#appended to the list that is returned at the end of the call.
# trim : Returns the string with all leading and trailing whitespace removed.
my @data1= fmap { trim($_)  } $file_1;
my @data2= fmap { trim($_)  } $file_2;

#Create a List::Compare object. Put the two lists into arrays (named or anonymous) 
# and pass references to the arrays to the constructor.
my $diff_file1 = List::Compare->new(\@data1, \@data2);
#get_unique() : Get those items which appear (at least once) only in the first list.
my @data_missing_file2 = $diff_file1->get_unique;

my $diff_file2 = List::Compare->new(\@data2, \@data1);
my @data_missing_file1 = $diff_file2->get_unique;

print "Data missing in file2 which present in file1 : ",  Dumper(\@data_missing_file2) , "\n";
print "Data missing in file1 which present in file2: ", Dumper(\@data_missing_file1) , "\n";
```

> Output

```
Data missing in file2 which present in file1 : $VAR1 = [
          '15122',
          '16008',
          '16018',
          '16023',
          '16025',
          '16040',
          '16041',
          '16042',
          '16043',
          '16045',
          '16114',
          '16226',
          '16704',
          '16712',
          '16910',
          '16911',
          '16912',
          '16913',
          '16914',
          '16915',
          '16916',
          '7308'
        ];

Data missing in file1 which present in file2: $VAR1 = [
          '15211',
          '16024',
          '16051',
          '16201',
          '16225',
          '16350'
        ];
```